# Eclipselink history the addEndFieldName

Tags: java, eclipselink

Advance thanks to you all.

I have a problem working with Eclipselink History. The addEndFieldName always turns null. The addStartFieldName has correct timestamp. It to works for insert and update. When the entity is deleted, there is no entry in the history table.

Please help me I am struggling with that for quiet sometime

Here is my code:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Customizer;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id_product")
private Integer idProduct;

.....
```

and DescriptorCustomizer is

```
public class TrackHistoryCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) {
        HistoryPolicy policy = new HistoryPolicy();
        policy.addHistoryTableName(descriptor.getTableName(), descriptor.getTableName() + "_history");
        policy.addStartFieldName("start_date");
        policy.addEndFieldName("end_date");
        policy.setShouldHandleWrites(true);
        descriptor.setHistoryPolicy(policy);
    }
}
```

Here is the output of my history table

> id_product  start_date              end_date
>   30          2017-03-14 17:19:53.000 ""
>   30          2017-03-14 17:27:16.000 ""
>   30          2017-03-14 17:31:32.000 ""

The end_date field is always null. The delete operation is also not inserted into the table.

I could not uderstand why it is happenning. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: A null endField seems to indicates the most current changes.  Your history table only shows a single ID field - IDs are not modifiable so there isn't going to be much in the way of history to record.  How are you removing entities?

Comment: I have made the id field and start_date field as primary keys for the history table. I am removing through entityManager.remove method

Comment: Turn on logging and run a simple test.  Persist a new entity in one transaction and  commit, then remove it in another transaction right after and show the log EclipseLink generates - it should log the SQL it tries to use and might give you an indication of why there isn't a history entry for the delete.

Comment: When I persist the query generated is as follows INSERT INTO product_history (id_product, active, country_market, data_status, date_created, date_modified, doseage_form, group_code, manufacturer, product_code, product_description, product_name, strength, email_id, id_language_code, id_status, packaging_size, start_date) There is no end_date. When I delete I got the following UPDATE product_history SET end_date = ? WHERE ((end_date IS NULL) AND (id_product = ?)) and there is no start_date. I really don't know what is hapenning. Thanks very much @Chris

Answer (score 0):

The history table works such that when you persist a new entity, a row goes into the history table showing this data with a start date, but no end date, as the data is still there.  WHen you change something, the previous history row gets an end date, and a new entry is put in to reflect the current state.  The current state always has an null end-date, as it is still active.  This allows you to audit changes and see when each was made and how long they were there before the next update.

When you remove a row, the previous history row just gets an end date.  There then should be no rows in the history table representing the removed entity with a null end date as there is no current data for it.

Comment: Thanks very much Chris. History table need a primary key, if I put a long id with auto_increment, the history policy still knows which rows to update.

Comment: I'm not a DBA, but what is the point of adding an auto incrementing id field if it isn't used by anything? Technically the row has an ID - the entity ID and start date

Comment: It means do I have to add a column row-id in the history table. If eclipselink can create the history table on the fly, it will be great. I understand for the moment it does not. My history table contains exact mirror copy of the entity with start_date and end_date. I ma having trouble in determinig the primary key for the history table. Thanks very much Chris.